# Array de baixo pra cima - Python

Tags: python

Eu consegui fazer como o problema pede, com o código abaixo, o único problema é que eu não consigo fazer com que o usuário coloque as coordenadas 0,0, só fica com coluna 0 e a linha não fica 0, fica 1. Eu quero que o usuário possa escolher a opção das paredes para que seja na linha 0 e não na linha 1.

**OBJETIVO:**

• Construir um ambiente cuja forma é uma matriz de tamanho variável de N
linhas por M colunas.

**REQUISITOS FUNCIONAIS DO AMBIENTE MATRIZ**

O software deve:

− permitir ao usuário definir como entrada os valores de N e M;

− permitir ao usuário definir paredes em posições quaisquer;

− permitir ao usuário escolher a posição inicial do objeto móvel;

− a coordenada (0,0) se encontra no canto inferior esquerdo da matriz;

− ser capaz de representar um objeto móvel que se desloca na matriz;

− o objeto móvel é capaz de se deslocar uma casa por vez em qualquer direção
ao receber um comando ir(x)tal x ∈ {N, NE, L, SE, S, SO, O, NO};

− o objeto móvel deve permanecer na mesma posição se receber um comando
impossível de ser executado: que o movimente para fora do grid ou que o faça
bater em uma parede;

− o objeto móvel deve ser capaz de retornar sua posição atual ao receber o comando
lerPos().

A cada ciclo, o software deve:

− perguntar ao usuário qual o comando a ser enviado ao objeto móvel (ir(x) ou
lerPos());

− ao receber um comando, o objeto móvel executará a ação correspondente;

− imprimir o estado atual do ambiente.

```
# Importando o numpy (lib do python para manipulação de array):
import numpy as np

# Pedindo ao usuário o tamanho do tabuleiro:
row = int(input('Informe o número de linhas: '))
col = int(input('Informe o número de colunas: '))
print('')

# Criando o tabuleiro com números 0 representando os caminhos livres:
tabuleiro = np.zeros(row*col).reshape(row, col)
print(tabuleiro)
print('')

# Pedindo as coordenadas de uma parede ao usuário dentro de um while para poder ter quantas paredes 
ele quiser:
while True:
  parede_x = int(input('Informe a coordenada X de uma parede: '))
  parede_y = int(input('Informe a coordenada Y de uma parede: '))
  tabuleiro[parede_x:parede_x+1, parede_y:parede_y+1] = 8 # A parede é representada pelo número 8
  print('')
  print(tabuleiro)
  print('')
  opc = input('Deseja colocar mais paredes no tabuleiro? (s / n) ')
  if opc == 's':
    pass
  elif opc == 'n':
    break
  else:
    print('Opção inválida! Digite s para sim e n para não.')

# Pedindo ao usuário o ponto de partida representado por 1:
x = int(input('Informe a linha do ponto de partida sabendo que a contagem começa em 0: '))
y = int(input('Informe a coluna do ponto de partida sabendo que a contagem começa em 0: '))
inicio = tabuleiro
inicio[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 1
lerPos = np.copy(inicio)
print('')
print(inicio)
print('')

# Passando as direções de onde eu quero andar (sua posição atual é representado por 2):
while True:
  mov = input("Para saber sua posição atual digite 'lerPos' \nPara qual direção você deseja ir?\n [1] - NORTE\n"+
                        " [2] - SUL\n [3] - LESTE\n [4] - OESTE\n [5] - NORDESTE\n"+
                        " [6] - NOROESTE\n [7] - SULDESTE\n [8] - SULDOESTE\n [0] - SAIR\n")
  if mov == '1':
    if lerPos[x-1:x, y:y+1] != 8:
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 0
      x -= 1
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 2
    else:
      print('Você bateu na parede!')
  elif mov == '2':
    if lerPos[x+1:x+2, y:y+1] != 8:
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 0
      x += 1
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 2
    else:
      print('Você bateu na parede!')
  elif mov == '3':
    if lerPos[x:x+1, y-1:y] != 8:
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 0
      y -= 1
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 2
    else:
      print('Você bateu na parede!')
  elif mov == '4':
    if lerPos[x:x+1, y+1:y+2] != 8:
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 0
      y += 1
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 2
    else:
      print('Você bateu na parede!')
  elif mov == '5':
    if lerPos[x-1:x, y+1:y+2] != 8:
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 0
      x -= 1
      y += 1
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 2
    else:
      print('Você bateu na parede!')
  elif mov == '6':
    if lerPos[x-1:x, y-1:y] != 8:
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 0
      x -= 1
      y -= 1
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 2
    else:
      print('Você bateu na parede!')
  elif mov == '7':
    if lerPos[x+1:x+2, y-1:y] != 8:
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 0
      x += 1
      y -= 1
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 2
    else:
      print('Você bateu na parede!')
  elif mov == '8':
    if lerPos[x+1:x+2, y+1:y+2] != 8:
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 0
      x += 1
      y += 1
      lerPos[x:x+1, y:y+1] = 2
    else:
      print('Você bateu na parede!')
  elif mov == '0':
    break
  elif mov == 'lerPos':
    print('({}, {})'.format(x, y))
  else:
    print('Opção inválida! Selecione uma direção válida.')

  print(lerPos)
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Falta mais informações na sua pergunta. Sugiro explicar de forma *bem detalhada* qual é o propósito do seu código, o que ele faz, o que você gostaria que ele fizesse e o que você acha que está de errado nele. Sua questão está recebendo pontos negativos porque faltam essas informações e seu código é bem extenso. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ok, Fernando. Feito, detalhei mais o objetivo do código.